# Cloud 9 & Rails: Cannot GET /dev_focus/focus/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, c9.io

I am following through with the [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset)
but have come to a bump in the road when trying to preview my mailers using the Cloud 9 IDE.

Here is my user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

def account_activation(user)
   @user=user
   mail to: user.email, subject: "Activate your focus. account"
end

def password_reset
  @greeting = "Hi"

  mail to: "to@example.org"
end
end
```

My problem is when I attempt to preview my mailers using the link

http://*ide.c9.io/-workspacename-*/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation

I get a blank page with the following error:

Cannot GET /dev_focus/focus/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation

Any Ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue:

Cloud 9 Project was set to private, and you must set it to public in order to preview your mailers!